# Showing stopping is finite almost surely

Tags: random-walk, stopping-times

Consider a discrete random walk taking values +1 or -1 with probabilities p and q, respectively. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$. Let $[-A,B]$ be an interval, $A,B \geq 1$. Now define 
$$\tau =\min(n:n \geq 0, S_n \leq -A \cup S_n \geq B).$$

I need to show that $\tau$ is finite almost surely.

What I am trying: 
$P_0(\tau < \infty) = P_0(\exists n<\infty \mbox{ so that } {S_n=-A}\mbox{ or }{S_n=B})$

Can someone put me in the right direction here? My hint was to use strong law of large numbers.

Comment: The hint to use some law of large numbers works like a charm when $p\ne q$ and fails miserably when $p=q$. Do you assume that $p\ne q$? (If you do not, you should sue the author of the "hint"...)

Comment: @Did The author makes no assumptions about $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Then, can you think of a basic fact implying the result when $p\ne q$?

Comment: @Did of course. The super/sub martingale would tend to positive /negative infinity in the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following extremely useful proposition "What always stands a reasonable chance of happening will (almost surely) happen - sooner rather than later."

Let $T$ a stopping time such that for some $N$ and $\epsilon>0$ we have for all $n$ that $P(T \leq n + N|\mathcal{F}_n) > \epsilon$ a.s., then $E[T] < \infty$, and in particular $T<\infty$ a.s.

Hint: Using induction and $P(T > kN) = P(T>kN; T>(k-1)N)$ show $P(T > kN) \leq (1-\epsilon)^k$.

Now how can we apply the proposition (which is exercise E10.5 in David Williams' *Probability with Martingales*)? No matter where you are in your random walk, you always have a fixed positive probability $p^{A+B}>0$ that the next $A+B$ coin flips are heads, in which case you stop in at most $A+B$ steps. Thus the proposition implies $E[\tau] < \infty$.

Comment: "What always stands a reasonable chance of happening will (almost surely) happen - sooner rather than later." Of course this needs to be qualified: assume that $X_n=X_1$ with $X_1$ standard normal then $P(X_n>0)=\frac12$ for every $n$ hence $X_n>0$ "always stands a reasonable chance of happening" and yet $P(\exists n,X_n>0)\ne1$.

Comment: Yes, one should be careful to always keep the theorem statement in mind so as to not let the language deceive. In your case $P(X_n > 0) = \frac{1}{2}$, but the theorem would require $P(X_n > 0 \cup \ldots \cup X_{n+N} > 0 | \mathcal{F}_n) > \epsilon$, which is of course false.

Comment: nullUser, have you any idea how to show such proposition applies to any stopping time (when applicable) ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562635/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-that-et-inf-n-x-n-b-infty

Comment: nullUser what are the $N$ and $\epsilon$ in this case?

Comment: @BCLC $N=A+B$ and $\epsilon = p^{A+B}$.

Comment: @nullUser aaahhhh thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 5):

We need notation. Say $X_1,\dots$ are iid with the specified distribution, and $$S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n.$$

Say $N=A+B$. Note that if there exists $n$ with $$X_n=X_{n+1}=\dots=X_{n+N-1}=1$$then $\tau<\infty$ (because why, exactly?).

So let $E_n$ be the event $$X_{nN}=X_{nN+1}=\dots=X_{(n+1)N-1}=1.$$The events $E_n$ are independent, and $\bigcup_n E_n$ implies $\tau<\infty$. So it's enough to show $$P\left(\bigcup_nE_n\right)=1.$$This follows from Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: So you are proposing that the problem is equivalent to showing the stopping time to hit A+B is finite. That makes sense. I don't understand how you are defining the event $E_n$.

Comment: No, I didn't say anything about the time to hit $A+B$. I don't understand what you don't understand about the definition of $E_n$.

Comment: I am still trying to digest your argument. So if $E_n$ happens, we guarantee the stopping time is finite almost surely?

Comment: No. If $E_n$ happens then the stopping time is finite. Say $F$ is the event "stopping time is finite". Then $E_n\subset F$. (Hence the stopping time is finite if $\bigcup_nE_n$ happens, and it turns out that that union has probability $1$.)

Comment: Would it be possible to make your definition of $E_n$ more clear? I am trying to use examples to understand what it is, but I am still confused by the meaning.

Comment: @Ryan Would it be possible to make clearer the problem you have with the **explicit** definition of En in this post?

Comment: @Did Sorry I am being unclear. I don't what to say though. I just don't understand why we wish to study that particular event. I understand everything written before $E_n$ is introduced.

Comment: We study $E_n$ because it's simple enough that we can figure out things about it, but it also has the property that it implies a finite stopping time. If at some point you take $A+B$ steps in the same direction you must have hit the wall, right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I agree with you in the fact that if you take A+B steps in the same direction, then you must hit the wall. Maybe it would help if you added another realization of $E_n$ in between the 'dot dot dot'. Again, sorry that I cannot be more helpful in explaining what I don't understand.

Comment: $$E_n=\bigcap_{k=1}^N\{X_{nN+k-1}=1\}.$$