# Asymmetric Random Walk / Prove that $E[\inf\{n: X_n = b\}] < \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Given random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots \stackrel{iid}{\sim} P(Y_i = 1) = p = 1 - q = 1 - P(Y_i = -1)$ where $p > q$ in a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$ where $\mathscr F_n = \mathscr F_n^Y$,

define $X = (X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $X_0 = 0$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$.

It can be shown that the stochastic process $M = (M_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $M_n = X_n - n(p-q)$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$-martingale.

Let $b$ be a positive integer and $T:= \inf\{n: X_n = b\}$.

It can be shown that [$T$ is a $\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$-stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562632/asymmetric-random-walk-prove-that-t-inf-n-x-n-b-is-a-mathscr-f).

### Prove that $E[T] < \infty$.

One proposition to use is '[What always stands a reasonable chance of happening will (almost surely) happen - sooner rather than later](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=e9saZ0YSi-AC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=%22what%20always%20stands%22%20%22probability%22&source=bl&ots=AWEio5s6Xq&sig=6kAyfQZorHRSFhYEVjQ83V7XGU4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje6t-I0MTJAhUleaYKHUa7AfIQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22what%20always%20stands%22%20%22probability%22&f=false)' (or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1468800/140308))

So let us show either that $\exists N \in \mathbb N, \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb N$,

$$P(T \le n + N \mid \mathscr F_n) > \epsilon$$

or the weaker condition that $\exists N \in \mathbb N, \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb N$,

$$P(T > kN) \le (1 - \epsilon)^k$$

---

I tried the first one:

$$P(T \le \infty \mid \mathscr F_n) = E(1_{T \le \infty} \mid \mathscr F_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{T=i} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} E[1_{T=i} \mid \mathscr F_n]$$

Hence, we must find and integer $N$ and a positive number $\epsilon$ s.t.

$$P(T \le n + N \mid \mathscr F_n) = E(1_{T \le n + N} \mid \mathscr F_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{T=i} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+N} E[1_{T=i} \mid \mathscr F_n] > \epsilon$$

where $\forall i > n$,

$$E[1_{T=i} \mid \mathscr F_n] = P(T=i \mid \mathscr F_n)$$

$$= P(X_i = b, X_1 \ne b, X_2 \ne b, \ldots, X_n \ne b, \ldots, X_{i-1} \ne b \mid \mathscr F_n)$$

$$= \prod_{j=1}^{n} 1_{X_j \ne b} E[1_{X_i = b} \prod_{j=n+1}^{i-1} 1_{X_j \ne b} \mid \mathscr F_n]$$

---

That's all I got. How can I use the proposition? Might there be another way I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and easy: since $M_n$ is a martingale, by optional stopping, for any $k$ we have $E[M_{T \wedge k}] = E[M_0] = 0$.  Rearranging, this says
$$E[T \wedge k] = \frac{1}{p-q} E[X_{T \wedge k}] \le \frac{b}{p-q}$$
since $X_{T \wedge k} \le b$.  By monotone convergence, $E[T] = \lim_{k \to \infty} E[T \wedge k]$, so $E[T] \le \frac{b}{p-q} < \infty$.

Comment: Seriously? I think somewhere in your argument you assumed $E[T] < \infty$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BCLC: I'm pretty sure I didn't.  Note that until the very last line, we are only working with the stopping time $T \wedge k$, which is bounded.  And monotone convergence doesn't require assuming $E[T]<\infty$.

Comment: And if you're worried about $X_{T \wedge k}$, note that in addition to being bounded above by $b$, it's bounded below by $-k$.  So its expectation is also finite.

Comment: MCT myb not but what about after MCT? How do you know the equality in the last line is true? Because $T < \infty$? I think I read a proof on that. Didn't think it was important

Comment: @BCLC: The equality in the last line ***is*** the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. How do you know $T \wedge k \to T$ ?

Comment: It's basically just the definition of "limit".  Fix $\omega$.  If $T(\omega) < \infty$, then there exists an integer $N$ so large that $N \ge T(\omega)$.  For all $k \ge N$ we have $T(\omega) \wedge k = T(\omega)$.  Hence $T(\omega) \wedge k \to T(\omega)$.  If $T(\omega) = \infty$ then $T(\omega) \wedge k = k \to \infty = T(\omega)$.  In either case $T(\omega) \wedge k \to T(\omega)$, and $\omega$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Wow so like you seem better than Williams :O Thanks Nate Eldredge! ^-^ I think you didn't use [optional stopping](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1564849/140308), but rather [this thm based on a probability principle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539854) ?

Comment: @BCLC: You can call it what you like.  It is a special case of the optional stopping theorem, applied to the bounded stopping time $T \wedge k$.